# javascript chaining promises clarification

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise, q

I'm trying to figure the concept of promises in javascript.

I've looked at this code:

```
new Promise(function(res,rej) {
    res("aaa");
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    return "bbb";
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    return "ccc";
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

it prints:

```
 aaa

 bbb

 ccc
```

to the console log.

a few questions:

1. is the `then()` method 1'st parameter is a function that will be run as the `resolve()` method?
2. is the `then()` method also returns a value which is a promise and this promise is the same promise as the one it is linked to (its parent) **only the value of its `resolve()` method is the value return from the `resolve()` method inside the `then()`**?
3. is this promise:

   ```
   var myPromise = new Promise(function(res,rej) {
       res("aaa");
   })
   .then(function(result) {
       console.log(result);
       return "bbb";
   })
   ```

is equivalents to this promise below?

```
var myPromise = new Promise(function(res,rej) {
    res("bbb");
})
```

in addition, what is happening when the `then()` accepts a promise?

like in this example?

```
var firstMethod = function() {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log('first method completed');
         resolve({data: '123'});
      }, 2000);
   });
   return promise;
};


var secondMethod = function(someStuff) {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log('second method completed');
         resolve({newData: someStuff.data + ' some more data'});
      }, 2000);
   });
   return promise;
};

var thirdMethod = function(someStuff) {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log('third method completed');
         resolve({result: someStuff.newData});
      }, 3000);
   });
   return promise;
};

firstMethod()
   .then(secondMethod)
   .then(thirdMethod);
```

Comment: A `Promise` represents a future value. `then` enables you to apply  normal functions to this "future value" wrapped in a `Promise`. These normal functions expect a value (which is provided by the Promise) and return a transformed value, which is again wrapped in a new `Promise`. That's the usual scenario.

Comment: There are too many questions here. You need to ask one question at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The then method's first param is the resolve function and the second param is the rejection function.

```js
var resolvedPromise = new Promise(function(res,rej){ res({data: 7}) });
var rejectedPromise = new Promise(function(res,rej){ rej('error!!!!') });
resolvedPromise.then(function(res){ console.log('resolved:' + JSON.stringify(res)); }, function (err){ console.log('rejected:' + err); });
rejectedPromise.then(function(res){ console.log('resolved:' + JSON.stringify(res)); }, function (err){ console.log('rejected:' + err); });
```

2. The then method returns a promise based on the return type of the previous promise.

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(res,rej){ res({data: 7}) });
promise.
then(function(res){ console.log(res); return res.data; }).
then(function(res){ console.log(res); return res + 1; }).
then(function(res){ console.log(res);});
```

3. No. The first code will log "aaa" and return a promise with "bbb" while the second will return "bbb" without logging "aaa";

Comment: what happened when the then() gets a promise as a parameter?